# Creating database link in posgresSQL to connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, postgresql

Are there any way to connect PostgreSQL to SQL Server? I found this link http://pgfoundry.org/projects/dblink-tds/ but are there other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would best suggest to design ETL process in [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) or [Talend](https://www.talend.com/) and separate data integration and data storage layer. It's easier to manage then making db link.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do something using one of PostgreSQL's server languages, e.g. pl/pythonu.  For any given query you could write a function in that language which fetches the results from the remote server, using the language's own DB access modules.  So in pl/pythonu you would use a Python DB-API module for SQL Server access.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server

Answer (score 2):

You could try a foreign data wrapper.

There is one for accessing Microsoft SQL Server and an ODBC based one.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

I have not used them, so I have no idea how good they are.